# Adding custom attributes

Tags: html, attributes, custom-attributes, custom-data-attribute

In a rather complex HTML5 webapp that I am creating I find that it is handy to add a few custom attributes to some document elements.  With jQuery I find that I can retrieve such attributes without any issues - in Chrome, Safari and Firefox thus far and, I hope, also on the Android/iPhone mobile browsers.

Question - is such usage, injecting custom attributes, ok or will I be breaking something down the line.  To get things into context I am using jQuery Mobile, with jQuery and a few jQuery plugins.

On a related note I assume it is possible to retrieve all elements with a specified attribute with jQuery?

Comment: Prefix them with `data-`: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: Thanks! I guess I have been seeing this all the time in jQuery Mobile without realizing what it meant.  Like I said a few hours ago - what a great little forum this is! Seconds  from question to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using custom attributes, I would recommend using data attributes , which you can read about on the [HTML5 Doctor Website](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

Essentially, you can give elements custom attributes that are prefixed by `data-`, and you can read / set these with jQuery. Here's an example:

**HTML5 snippet:**

```
<p id="porky" data-food="bacon">Porky was a tasty little piggy</p>
```

**jQuery snippet:**

```
alert( $('#porky').data('food') ); // Alerts "bacon"
$('#porky').data('food', 'roast');
alert( $('#porky').data('food') ); // Alerts "roast"
```

Using the data-attributes will make for a valid, future-proof app.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `data-` attributes:

```
<div data-someattr="1" data-someotherattr="'1'" data-obj="{prop:'val1'}" ....
```

The retrieve those by [jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

```
$('div').data('someattr')           //1      Number
$('div').data('someotherattr')      //'1'    String
$('div').data('obj').prop          //'val1' String
```

Comment: Thank you!  Being able to wrap an object into an attribute is quite simply cooool